# passing parameters to function

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

from my knowledge I found that there are two ways of passing parameters to functions, 
- as parameters in function signature or - collect the parameters in object

Example:
if I have a summation function

```
public int Sum(parameters)
```

I need to know which is the better to pass the parameters, is it like this

```
public int Sum(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

or like that?

```
public int Sum(Number no) {
    return no.X + no.Y;
}

public class Number {
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference whatsoever. The second option you show is called encapsulation and is a practice used to bundle data into a single object. Different use cases for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no significant difference. The second method, having things inside an object, is called encapsulation. Encapsulating is usually better if you have a lot of parameters or a common set of parameters that get passed to other methods down the line. There is a very slight processing impact to encapsulation, but it shouldn't affect you in any perceivable way.

Having each variable be separate tends to make more sense for a smaller set of parameters and for methods that won't tend to pass those parameters to other methods.

In the end though, it's up to you what you use. As I said before, the impact of encapsulation is negligible, but it can be a hassle defining classes and structs for everything. I generally use encapsulation if there's a collection of variables that are often found together anyway that multiple methods use. Then certain methods can just ignore variables they don't need.

**Bonus Fact**

There's also a third way of passing parameters if you want a method to be able to accept an arbitrary number of things. This is done using the `params` keyword for a parameter, which then takes all the supplied parameters and sticks them in an array. In your sum case would work as follows:

```
public int Sum(params int[] args) //Accepts any number of int parameters
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
    {
       result += args[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which can then be called like:

```
Sum(1, 2);
Sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
or even
Sum(1);
```

`params` tends to have fewer uses though, and I'm unsure of the processing impact of it, but it's there if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you requirements and how many parameters you required to pass to the function. But if you want to pass many parameters then you should use second method by creating properties. It would be easy and more efficient.

Comment: While the difference is negligible, instantiating new objects is never more efficient than just simply passing the variables directly.

Comment: In case of few parameters, you are correct. but using models are easy if you want to make it type safe.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends of the complexity of your function. In this example the better approach is the first one. Since you dont need to create new objects to sum it up. If you have the necessity to right or read different times the return of your class you must use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should decide what data structure your application will have and after this use that structures to pass into methods. Its a good rule not to produce structures you have no need in. Some times you can nocited that several parameters have logical ties and alway (almost always) passed in methods all together. in this case I will recomend to encapsulate them into structure

Answer (score 0):

I would try to prefer always the first choice as is clear from the method signature what it actually does and at the same time you are sure that you pass in this method only what is actually needed.

And also if you see that your method has too many parameters, it may be warn signal of bad design. So in the end second choice may be only a hack how to hide some design issues.